# Linha TOTAL com o SUM das colunas usando PIVOT

Tags: sql, pivot

Será possível fazer uma linha de TOTAIS por coluna? A explicação dos totais por linha foi fantástica e resultou lindo na meu projeto.
Obrigada.

O meu código:

```
SELECT 
    ano AS Ano, 
    CCUSTOS AS [Centro custos], 
    coalesce([1], 0) janeiro, 
    coalesce([2], 0) fevereiro, 
    coalesce([3], 0) março, 
    coalesce([4], 0) abril, 
    coalesce([5], 0) maio, 
    coalesce([6], 0) junho, 
    coalesce([7], 0) julho, 
    coalesce([8], 0) agosto, 
    coalesce([9], 0) setembro, 
    coalesce([10], 0) outubro, 
    coalesce([11], 0) novembro, 
    coalesce([12], 0) dezembro,
    coalesce([1],0)+ coalesce([2],0)+ coalesce([3],0)+ coalesce([4],0)+ coalesce([5],0)+ coalesce([6],0)+ coalesce([7],0)+ coalesce([8],0)+ coalesce([9],0)+ coalesce([10],0)+ coalesce([11],0)+ coalesce([12],0) AS Total
FROM V_despesas_group_CC
PIVOT (SUM(total_valor) FOR MES IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]))P
ORDER BY CCUSTOS
```

Comment: @RovannLinhalis acabei respondendo que _é possível_, mas como você falou, não via _pivot_.. já fui mandando a gambiarra xD

Comment: na hr q vi a resposta até apaguei o comentário... vai q é possível e eu que não sabia... aí fui ler a resposta....rsrsrs mas então, da forma que você fez ainda é outro jeito, e não vai colocar o resultado na própria coluna...vai gerar outras colunas com os valores repetidos em todas as linhas.... voltando... no pivot não, talvez usaria o union, mas teria que fazer uma gambiarra pra garantir que a linha ficasse no final. Dependendo de como e onde está utilizando a query, faria isso pelo código...

Comment: ah, entendi.. ainda acho que o ideal seria tratar esse total no código, mas deixa a autora se pronunciar.

Comment: SQL 2008 e no PHP estou a fazer a criaçao de ficheiro Excel com o conteúdo do PIVOT. Vou mostrar o que tenho feito :)

$filename = "Listagem_despesas_CCusto"; $file_ending = "xls"; header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.$file_ending"); header("Pragma: no-cache"); header("Expires: 0"); $stmt = mssql_init('[passes].[dbo].[sp_pivot_despesas]'); $result = mssql_execute($stmt); $sep = "\t"; echo '<table border="1">'; $header = false;

Comment: while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 if (!$header) {
   // Table header
      echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
          while($field = mssql_fetch_field($result)){
            echo '<th>' . $field->name . '</th>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
      echo '</thead>';
   $header = true;
 }

Comment: echo '<tbody>';
       echo '<tr>';
         foreach($row as $value) {
            if(!isset($value)){
              $value = "0";
            }
            $value = str_replace(".", ",", $value);
           echo '<td>' .   $value  . '</td>';

           }
    echo '</tr>';

Comment: Esqueci dizer que é uma Stored Procedure que fiz para poder ser chamada no PHP ...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE (MES INT, VALOR INT);
INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (1, 1000);
INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (1, 1150);
INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (1, 1200);
INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (2, 4500);
INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (2, 1000);
INSERT INTO TESTE VALUES (3, 690);

SELECT * FROM (SELECT MES, SUM(VALOR) AS TOTAL FROM TESTE GROUP BY MES) AS X PIVOT ( SUM(TOTAL) FOR MES IN ([1],[2],[3]) ) AS P
```

Para juntar na linha inferior, adicione um UNION ALL:

```
SELECT 
    ano AS Ano, 
    CCUSTOS AS [Centro custos], 
    coalesce([1], 0) janeiro, 
    coalesce([2], 0) fevereiro, 
    coalesce([3], 0) março, 
    coalesce([4], 0) abril, 
    coalesce([5], 0) maio, 
    coalesce([6], 0) junho, 
    coalesce([7], 0) julho, 
    coalesce([8], 0) agosto, 
    coalesce([9], 0) setembro, 
    coalesce([10], 0) outubro, 
    coalesce([11], 0) novembro, 
    coalesce([12], 0) dezembro,
    coalesce([1],0)+ coalesce([2],0)+ coalesce([3],0)+ coalesce([4],0)+ coalesce([5],0)+ coalesce([6],0)+ coalesce([7],0)+ coalesce([8],0)+ coalesce([9],0)+ coalesce([10],0)+ coalesce([11],0)+ coalesce([12],0) AS Total
FROM V_despesas_group_CC
PIVOT (SUM(total_valor) FOR MES IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]))P

UNION ALL

SELECT
P.ANO AS ANO,
P.CCUSTOS AS [CENTRO CUSTO],
P.[1] AS JANEIRO
...
P.[12] AS DEZEMBRO
FROM (SELECT MES, SUM(VALOR) AS TOTAL FROM TESTE GROUP BY MES) AS X PIVOT ( SUM(TOTAL) FOR MES IN ([1],[2],[3]) ) AS P
```

Não recomendo realizar a tratativa via linguagem web (PHP, Java, Python, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

É possível:

```
SELECT 
    ano AS Ano, 
    CCUSTOS AS [Centro custos], 
    coalesce([1], 0) janeiro, 
    coalesce([2], 0) fevereiro, 
    coalesce([3], 0) março, 
    coalesce([4], 0) abril, 
    coalesce([5], 0) maio, 
    coalesce([6], 0) junho, 
    coalesce([7], 0) julho, 
    coalesce([8], 0) agosto, 
    coalesce([9], 0) setembro, 
    coalesce([10], 0) outubro, 
    coalesce([11], 0) novembro, 
    coalesce([12], 0) dezembro,
    coalesce([1],0)+ coalesce([2],0)+ coalesce([3],0)+ coalesce([4],0)+ coalesce([5],0)+ coalesce([6],0)+ coalesce([7],0)+ coalesce([8],0)+ coalesce([9],0)+ coalesce([10],0)+ coalesce([11],0)+ coalesce([12],0) AS Total,
    (SELECT SUM(d2.total_valor) from V_despesas_group_CC d2 WHERE mes = 1) as Total_Janeiro,
    (SELECT SUM(d2.total_valor) from V_despesas_group_CC d2 WHERE mes = 2) as Total_Fevereiro --e assim para demais meses do ano
FROM V_despesas_group_CC
PIVOT (SUM(total_valor) FOR MES IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]))P
ORDER BY CCUSTOS
```

Porém essa solução é custosa, já que para cada linha ele vai executar as *subconsultas*.

Minha sugestão é que você faça esse controle via código; caso não seja possível, isso pode ser adicionado a uma tabela temporária.

Se tiver dúvidas/problemas, comenta pra tentarmos *arrumar* a resposta.

Comment: Obrigada rLinhares pela resposta.
Esta solução que me sugeres faz os sumatórios mas coloca-os em linhas ao lado do TOTAL que já tenho repetindo em cada linha o total das colunas.
O meu objetivo é que apareçam esses totais na linha inferior.
Muito obrigada

Comment: Não sei fazer o que sugeres, fazer em código uma tabela temporária :(

Comment: O que você está usando (php, java, c#, ...)? o fazer _via código_ seria na linguagem que irá receber a consulta; tabela temporária seria fazer tudo via _sql_ mesmo. A propósito, qual banco está usando??

Comment: SQL 2008 e no PHP estou a fazer a criaçao de ficheiro Excel com o conteúdo do PIVOT.  O PIVOT está criado numa Stored Procudure e é chamada no código em PHP

Comment: você não acha que vale controlar o totalizador mensal no próprio php? acho mais performático que a solução que eu apresentei.

Comment: Vou tentar com o <tfoot>, não tenho ainda a solução de como fazer, pensei foreach($row as $value) {
       $value = str_replace(".", ",", $value);
        echo '<td>' . $value+=$value . '</td>';
      },  mas não resulta...